# Why RAM only being used by process instead of SWAP , how can we troubleshoot this issue?

Tags: tomcat, memory, swap, ram

Tomcat processes are consuming more memory in the linux server . When we check RAM was almost used 99% and SWAP is not used by 20% also. Why Tomcat process is not using SWAP and its using more RAM ?

Comment: Most IT people would kill for this situation. First time I've ever seen it presented as a problem, in 41 years.

Answer (score 2):

The general design assumption of an operating system is that unused RAM is forever wasted. If your system has 4GB, you can't use 2GB today so that you can use 6GB tomorrow. So operating systems do everything they possibly can not to leave RAM unused and thereby waste it.

Sometimes people think something like, "I want that RAM free now so that I can use it later." But that's silly. You can both use it now and use it later. There's *no* tradeoff here.

When a system is not under any memory pressure, it generally will use very little swap, if any. It may copy into swap information that hasn't been used in a very long time. But it may not bother until it starts to sense some memory pressure. So very low swap usage is normal.